# How to query Azure AD for password expiration date?

Tags: vb.net, azure-active-directory, desktop-application

I've got a VB.NET app that queries the local AD for password expiration date. Works fine. But.... the firm is moving to Azure AD and the same app no longer works. Most of the examples I'm finding are about Powershell or web apps. Can anyone point me to advice for .NET desktop apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the app check this date at all? If you try to log in via AD with an expired password, the login is denied. There's no need to check expiration separately. If you're showing this to the user in the app... that's not your app's job, unless the purpose of the app is specifically managing the account. And if the purpose of the app is managing the account... maybe this should have been addressed long before the moving to  Azure AD (which, btw, has it's own account management solution built in)

Comment: That's part of the app's purpose.